# python finding string in dataframe at special column

Tags: python

i want to check "load_post_page" at row i of columns "action" exist or not but i got this error:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

````
for i in range(len(actions)):
    if actions[i].str.contains('load_post_page') :
      print("yes") ```
````

Comment: is `actions` a pandas dataFrame?

Comment: yes but data saved string at it. i checked type of data in rows and they are strings

Comment: With this looping procedure, please try `if "load_post_page" in actions[i]` because `actions` is probably a `pd.Series` and its entries are strings; and "contains" for strings are done with the `in` operator.

Comment: `for i in range(len(...))` is not Pythonic here; you can go for `for action in actions:` and then in the loop `if "load_post_page" in action:`.

Comment: it worked. but if the row of action column contain "load post page "i wanted to append all of columns of that row to the empty dataframe `for i in range(len(actions)):
    if "load_post_page" in actions[i] :
      load_df.append(sumcamp[i])  ` but i got keyerror 0

Comment: use `load_df = sumcamp[actions.str.contains('load_post_page'])`

Comment: but i want to check that in action[i]

Answer (score 0):

*Try always to make a minimum reproducible example of your problem.*

Accessing elements from a Series will return you the element. For example `actions[0]` will give you `'qweasd'`, which is a string. And on a string the pandas method for `Series` like `.str` does not work. But you can make a regulat comparison with `==`.

```
import pandas as pd
actions = pd.Series(["qweasd", "fvoefj", "load_post_page"])
for i in range(len(actions)):
    if actions[i] == 'load_post_page':
        print('yes')
```

To make the check in pandas fashion, which is recommended, use the following snipped:

```
# or direct on your series
actions.str.contains('load_post_page')
# 0    False
# 1    False
# 2     True
```

According to your comment you like to select some rows with this condition.

```
load_df = sumcamp[actions.str.contains('load_post_page'])
```

`actions.str.contains('load_post_page']` give you a vector with `True` and `False` where the condition is met, like above. This boolean vector you can use to select the rows in your `sumcamp` data frame.

Hope that is worth a try.

Comment: so you mean i should delete if and for?

Comment: actually i want to split a dataframe into 2 dataframe by "action" column. where action is "load_post_page" all of rows and columns should be in load_df and where action is "click"_post" information should br in click_df

Comment: `click_df = sumcamp[actions.str.contains('click_post'])`